# How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator, but Java's library doesn't provide a sort function for ints with comparators (comparators can be used only with objects). Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: do you just want to sort the array in descending order or do you want to perform something more complicated?

Comment: Something more complicated. I want to sort the int using absolute value as a key.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you can't change the type of your input array the following will work:

```
final int[] data = new int[] { 5, 4, 2, 1, 3 };
final Integer[] sorted = ArrayUtils.toObject(data);
Arrays.sort(sorted, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // Intentional: Reverse order for this demo
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
});
System.arraycopy(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(sorted), 0, data, 0, sorted.length);
```

This uses [`ArrayUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) from the commons-lang project to easily convert between `int[]` and `Integer[]`, creates a copy of the array, does the sort, and then copies the sorted data over the original.

Comment: Why don't you use Arrays.sort instead of converting array -> list -> array?

Comment: Good point, I've updated, was playing around with commons-primitives, but didn't actually do anything useful

Comment: I didn't know about commons-lang. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `return o2.compareTo(o1);` is this correct? I believe this way the ordering will be reversed as we expect...

Comment: Yes the ordering is reversed, I chose that to prove that the ordering was different from the natural ordering of `int`

Answer (score 48):

How about using streams (Java 8)?

```
int[] ia = {99, 11, 7, 21, 4, 2};
ia = Arrays.stream(ia).
    boxed().
    sorted((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)). // sort descending
    mapToInt(i -> i).
    toArray();
```

Or in-place:

```
int[] ia = {99, 11, 7, 21, 4, 2};
System.arraycopy(
        Arrays.stream(ia).
            boxed().
            sorted((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)). // sort descending
            mapToInt(i -> i).
            toArray(),
        0,
        ia,
        0,
        ia.length
    );
```

Comment: It bugs me that we can't have sorted(IntComparator) on IntStream.

Comment: Don’t use `(a, b) -> b - a` for reverse order. This comparator can overflow. Mind the existence of `Comparator.reverseOrder()`…

Comment: Completely missed the potential overflow. Adapted the answer. Thanks Holger!

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`IntArrays.quickSort(array, comparator)`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntArrays.html#quickSort-int:A-it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints.IntComparator-) from fastutil library.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to copy the array (say it is very large), you might want to create a wrapper `List<Integer>` that can be used in a sort:

```
final int[] elements = {1, 2, 3, 4};
List<Integer> wrapper = new AbstractList<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return elements[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return elements.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
            int v = elements[index];
            elements[index] = element;
            return v;
        }

    };
```

And now you can do a sort on this wrapper List using a custom comparator.

Comment: I like this much better than the accepted response. No need to copy or convert array content, just take advantage of custom implementation of Lists.

Comment: @OB1: it looks neat, but the standard `sort` implementation copies the entire list into an array, sorts it and writes it back. And since this list doesn’t implement the `RandomAccess` marker, the write-back will be using a `ListIterator` instead of just calling `set`.

Comment: Wow, Holger is right about the copy. I didn't even think about checking this as I assumed that nobody would be so braindead to do a copy.

Comment: @user1460736 The javadocs say this is done on purpose, because list implementations might be inefficient for random access. E.g. `LinkedList` would be super bad to sort directly, thus they do a copy. Why they don't check for `RandomAccess` is not clear, I guess not many people know about this marker interface at all.

Comment: Extending `RandomAccess` would not hurt in case this optimization is performed at sometime in the future. However, currently the method doesn't achieve what it was set up to do.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need external library:

```
Integer[] input = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
Arrays.sort(input, (a, b) -> b - a); // reverse order
return Arrays.stream(input).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: To quote [Holgers comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator#comment63804518_33045466): "Don’t use `(a, b) -> b - a` for reverse order. This comparator can overflow. Mind the existence of `Comparator.reverseOrder()`"

Answer (score 3):

By transforming your int array into an Integer one and then using [`public static <T> void Arrays.sort(T[] a,
 Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) (the first step is only needed as I fear autoboxing may bot work on arrays).

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested with performance and reducing number of object created on the way consider using implementation from [eclipse collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.3.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/primitive/IntQuickSort.html).

It uses custom `IntComparator`, which operates on primitives thus no boxing is required.

Answer (score 2):

java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(new int[]{10,4,5,6,1,2,3,7,9,8}).boxed().sorted((e1,e2)-> e2-e1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code (it's actually not Timsort as I originally thought, but it does work well) that does the trick without any boxing/unboxing. In my tests, it works 3-4 times faster than using Collections.sort with a List wrapper around the array.

```
// This code has been contributed by 29AjayKumar 
// from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort/

static final int sortIntArrayWithComparator_RUN = 32; 

// this function sorts array from left index to  
// to right index which is of size atmost RUN  
static void sortIntArrayWithComparator_insertionSort(int[] arr, IntComparator comparator, int left, int right) { 
    for (int i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)  
    { 
        int temp = arr[i]; 
        int j = i - 1; 
        while (j >= left && comparator.compare(arr[j], temp) > 0)
        { 
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
            j--; 
        } 
        arr[j + 1] = temp; 
    } 
} 

// merge function merges the sorted runs  
static void sortIntArrayWithComparator_merge(int[] arr, IntComparator comparator, int l, int m, int r) { 
    // original array is broken in two parts  
    // left and right array  
    int len1 = m - l + 1, len2 = r - m; 
    int[] left = new int[len1]; 
    int[] right = new int[len2]; 
    for (int x = 0; x < len1; x++)  
    { 
        left[x] = arr[l + x]; 
    } 
    for (int x = 0; x < len2; x++)  
    { 
        right[x] = arr[m + 1 + x]; 
    } 

    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0; 
    int k = l; 

    // after comparing, we merge those two array  
    // in larger sub array  
    while (i < len1 && j < len2)  
    { 
        if (comparator.compare(left[i], right[j]) <= 0)
        { 
            arr[k] = left[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            arr[k] = right[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 

    // copy remaining elements of left, if any  
    while (i < len1) 
    { 
        arr[k] = left[i]; 
        k++; 
        i++; 
    } 

    // copy remaining element of right, if any  
    while (j < len2)  
    { 
        arr[k] = right[j]; 
        k++; 
        j++; 
    } 
} 

// iterative sort function to sort the  
// array[0...n-1] (similar to merge sort)  
static void sortIntArrayWithComparator(int[] arr, IntComparator comparator) { sortIntArrayWithComparator(arr, lIntArray(arr), comparator); }
static void sortIntArrayWithComparator(int[] arr, int n, IntComparator comparator) { 
    // Sort individual subarrays of size RUN  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += sortIntArrayWithComparator_RUN)  
    { 
        sortIntArrayWithComparator_insertionSort(arr, comparator, i, Math.min((i + 31), (n - 1))); 
    } 

    // start merging from size RUN (or 32). It will merge  
    // to form size 64, then 128, 256 and so on ....  
    for (int size = sortIntArrayWithComparator_RUN; size < n; size = 2 * size)  
    { 
          
        // pick starting point of left sub array. We  
        // are going to merge arr[left..left+size-1]  
        // and arr[left+size, left+2*size-1]  
        // After every merge, we increase left by 2*size  
        for (int left = 0; left < n; left += 2 * size)  
        { 
              
            // find ending point of left sub array  
            // mid+1 is starting point of right sub array  
            int mid = Math.min(left + size - 1, n - 1);
            int right = Math.min(left + 2 * size - 1, n - 1); 

            // merge sub array arr[left.....mid] &  
            // arr[mid+1....right]  
            sortIntArrayWithComparator_merge(arr, comparator, left, mid, right); 
        } 
    } 
}

static int lIntArray(int[] a) {
  return a == null ? 0 : a.length;
}

static interface IntComparator {
  int compare(int a, int b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper method to do the job.

First of all you'll need a new Comparator interface, as [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) doesn't support primitives:

```
public interface IntComparator{
    public int compare(int a, int b);
}
```

(You could of course do it with autoboxing / unboxing but I won't go there, that's ugly)

Then, here's a helper method to sort an int array using this comparator:

```
public static void sort(final int[] data, final IntComparator comparator){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length + 0; i++){
        for(int j = i; j > 0
            && comparator.compare(data[j - 1], data[j]) > 0; j--){
            final int b = j - 1;
            final int t = data[j];
            data[j] = data[b];
            data[b] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is some client code. A stupid comparator that sorts all numbers that consist only of the digit '9' to the front (again sorted by size) and then the rest (for whatever good that is):

```
final int[] data =
    { 4343, 544, 433, 99, 44934343, 9999, 32, 999, 9, 292, 65 };
sort(data, new IntComparator(){

    @Override
    public int compare(final int a, final int b){
        final boolean onlyNinesA = this.onlyNines(a);
        final boolean onlyNinesB = this.onlyNines(b);
        if(onlyNinesA && !onlyNinesB){
            return -1;
        }
        if(onlyNinesB && !onlyNinesA){
            return 1;
        }

        return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b));
    }

    private boolean onlyNines(final int candidate){
        final String str = String.valueOf(candidate);
        boolean nines = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(!(str.charAt(i) == '9')){
                nines = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return nines;
    }
});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Output:

```
[9, 99, 999, 9999, 32, 65, 292, 433, 544, 4343, 44934343]
```

The sort code was taken from [Arrays.sort(int[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29), and I only used the version that is optimized for tiny arrays. For a real implementation you'd probably want to look at the source code of the internal method `sort1(int[], offset, length)` in the [Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.

Comment: Arrays.sort() seems to use quicksort looking at its code whereas the proposed sort seems to use insertion sort. Wouldn't it be asymptotically slower?

Comment: Yes, it's unacceptably slow unless the array is very short

Answer (score 0):

I tried maximum to use the comparator with primitive type itself. At-last i concluded that there is no way to cheat the comparator.This is my implementation.

```
public class ArrSortComptr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int[] array = { 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 6 };
         int[] sortedArr=SortPrimitiveInt(new intComp(),array);
         System.out.println("InPut "+ Arrays.toString(array));
         System.out.println("OutPut "+ Arrays.toString(sortedArr));

    }
 static int[] SortPrimitiveInt(Comparator<Integer> com,int ... arr)
 {
    Integer[] objInt=intToObject(arr);
    Arrays.sort(objInt,com);
    return intObjToPrimitive(objInt);

 }
 static Integer[] intToObject(int ... arr)
 {
    Integer[] a=new Integer[arr.length];
    int cnt=0;
    for(int val:arr)
      a[cnt++]=new Integer(val);
    return a;
 }
 static int[] intObjToPrimitive(Integer ... arr)
 {
     int[] a=new int[arr.length];
     int cnt=0;
     for(Integer val:arr)
         if(val!=null)
             a[cnt++]=val.intValue();
     return a;

 }

}
class intComp implements Comparator<Integer>
{

    @Override //your comparator implementation.
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }

}
```

@Roman:
I can't say that this is a good example but since you asked this is what came to my mind.
Suppose in an array you want to sort number's just based on their absolute value.

```
Integer d1=Math.abs(o1);
Integer d2=Math.abs(o2);
return d1.compareTo(d2);
```

Another example can be like you want to sort only numbers greater than 100.It actually depends on the situation.I can't think of any more situations.Maybe Alexandru can give more examples since he say's he want's to use a comparator for int array.

Comment: @Emil: sorry for a little offtop, but I'm just curious, could you please show me an example of comparator you've used to sort an array of integers? I just can't imagine none implementation except for `return sign * (i1 - i2);` where `sign` is -1 or +1 depending on desirable order.

Comment: @Emil: actually, implementation I've just shown is probably broken (ints should be casted to long at first) but it doesn't matter in the context.

Comment: Do you mean to say that a comparator for integer is not required other than ascending and descending order sort?

Comment: @Emil: almost yes, but I said that only I can't imagine another case.

Comment: @Roman:I appended a sample to the answer.I don't know if this was what you expected.

Comment: @Emil: ok, situations are seldom, but let it be.. thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Roman I had a thing where I had an int[] of model indices but I wanted to return them in view order so I was going to use `Comparator.comparing(table::convertRowIndexToView)` as my comparator. There are definitely cases where it's useful. :)