# Java library that perform sorting of primitives array with custom comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, primitive

Does anybody see library that can solve this problem? Default array sorting can't deal with custom comparators.

Comment: You can create an array of the corresponding wrapper class and sort that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: What's the point of sorting arrays of primitives with custom comparator ?

Comment: Can't add an answer, so here is the link: https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive

Custom comparator might be useful when the array in question contains indices into some other data array. And it's actually the data elements that need to be compared when sorting, not the indices themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Comparator` on the Objects only.You can't on the primitive types.
By using *ArrayUtils* class you can convert primitive array to wrapper and vice-versa .
So Use Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) class.

```
Integer objectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(array);   
Arrays.sort(objectArray,new MyComparator());
int[] sortedArray = ArraysUtils.toPrimitive(objectArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't require an answer but I think I must make you understand the reason behind this.

All the basic data types or primitive data types can only be compared in the order of their natural ordering. This is enforced by the language specification.

**Natural Ordering**: means that the obvious way how a group is arranged in nature. For e.g. if you consider natural numbers it is always true that `1 < 2 < 3 < ... < 10` and same is the case with other primitives like `char` etc.

This also makes a lot of sense and helps in optimization, because the primitive data types are used in the language in lot of places (like loop counters, switch statements etc) and the compiler can actually optimize a lot of things if it can assume the natural order of a type of variables.

There are many more points, but I am sure you got the reason why Arrays default sort doesn't provide custom Comparator for primitive data types.