# Sorting variables in objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with 3 Objects in it. Each Object is a new book in my case. Each book has different values for the title, retail price, quantity in stock, etc.

How do I compare and sort the retail price for all of the objects. I have heard of

```
Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<BookInfo>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(BookInfo book1, BookInfo book2) {
        return book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getTitle());
    }
});
```

with a custom Comparator, but I cannot use the `compareTo` method for doubles/ints. How would I implements this, or change it so I can compare doubles/ints?

Comment: Just use `<`, `==`, and `>` for comparing primitive values.

Comment: Yes this will work for only comparing two values, but what I need is to compare all the values and sort them.

Comment: @user3325783: to sort a list you just need a function that compares two values... maybe read some more about sort algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting to class Double and then compare:

```
Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<BookInfo>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(BookInfo book1, BookInfo book2) {
            Double p1 = book1.getRetailPrice();
            Double p2 = book2.getRetailPrice();
            return p1.compareTo(p2);
        }
    });
```

If you want to sort first after Price and second after Name:

```
Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<BookInfo>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(BookInfo book1, BookInfo book2) {
            Double p1 = book1.getRetailPrice();
            Double p2 = book2.getRetailPrice();
            int res = p1.compareTo(p2);
            if(res == 0){
                return book1.getTitle().compareTo(book2.getTitle());
            }
            return res;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this always

Assumption : price value is `Double`

```
   Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<BookInfo>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(BookInfo book1, BookInfo book2) {
        return book1.getPrice().compareTo(book2.getPrice());
    }
});
```

Reference : 
[How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: I don't think this will work because you can't derefence doubles. And the price is a double

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `Comparator` however you want, you only need to return a correct value, depending on comparison of the two objects:

- negative integer if `book1 < book2`
- positive integer if `book1 > book2`
- 0 if `book1 == book2`

  ```
  Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<BookInfo>() {
      @Override

      public int compare(BookInfo book1, BookInfo book2) {
          if (book1.getPrice() < book2.getPrice()) {
              return -1;
          } else if (book1.getPrice() > book2.getPrice()) {
              return 1;
          } else return 0;
      }
  });
  ```

This way you can customize the behaviour of `Comparator` anyway you like.