# java - 2d array sorting using 3rd column

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following code. When I try to compile it, it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>     The method sort(T[], Comparator) in the type Arrays is not applicable for >the arguments (int[][], new Comparator(){})
>
> at test.main.main(main.java:12)

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int [][] A = {{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5}};

        Arrays.sort(A, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
            public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
                Integer key1 = int1[2];
                Integer key2 = int2[2];
                return key1.compareTo(key2);
            }
        });


        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i][0] + ", " + A[i][1] + ", " + A[i][2]);
        }

    }
}
```

---

How can I solve this problem

Comment: An `Integer[]` is not an `int[]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator could be considered duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem using

```
Integer[][] A = ...;
```

instead of

```
int[][] A = ...;
```

You can get more information in this post: [Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types).

Answer (score 0):

You need not call `Arrays.sort(Integer[], Comparator);` Instead you can directly call `Arrays.sort(int[]);`.

Actually Integer has already implemented `Comparable`, therefore you may not define it again, until an unless you want to define some different sorting style!