# Sorting multiple attribute with Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

This is my list:

```
Name: Ben     || Age: 5 || Group: 1
Name: Andy    || Age: 6 || Group: 2
Name: Charlie || Age: 6 || Group: 2
Name: Ben     || Age: 5 || Group: 1
Name: Andy    || Age: 5 || Group: 2
Name: Charlie || Age: 5 || Group: 1
```

I want to sort the list by `Group`, if `Group` is equal then by `Age`, and if `Age` is equal then by `Name`. But so far I can only sort by one attribute, using Lambda Expressions:

```
list.sort((Object o1, Object o2) -> o1.getGroup().compareTo(o2.getGroup()));
```

If I try

```
o1.getGroup().compareTo(o2.getGroup()) && o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge())
```

it's turned out error...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change lambda *expression* to lambda *{block}*, and you don't have to specify the parameter types:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int cmp = o1.getGroup().compareTo(o2.getGroup());
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge());
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    return cmp;
});
```

Comment: You are the saviour of my day :) Thanks

Comment: @HuyVo The right way to thank somebody here is by upvoting their answers.

Comment: How to do this with raw arrays (not Lists)? This syntax does not seem to work when sorting an `int[] arr` with: `Arrays.sort(arr, <multi-line lambda>);`

Comment: @AnnaVopureta There are no sorting methods for sorting primitive arrays by custom order. The Java runtime library only has methods for sorting primitive arrays by their natural order. See: [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699141/5221149)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the static method [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to create a comparator based on a function that returns a comparable value. Such a comparator can be chained with others.

Assuming your type is called Person, you would have:

```
Comparator<Person> c = Comparator
        .comparing(p -> p.getGroup())
        .thenComparing(p -> p.getAge())
        .thenComparing(p -> p.getName())
```

If any of the getters return a primitive type, you have to use - for example - `comparingInt` and `thenComparingInt`, respectively. You can also use method references:

```
Comparator<Person> c = Comparator
        .comparing(Person::getGroup)
        .thenComparing(Person::getAge)
        .thenComparing(Person::getName)
```

But ... if your class has a *natural ordering* according to these values, you better let it implement the interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and write the compare logic in there:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        int compare = Integer.compare(getGroup(), other.getGroup());
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = Integer.compare(getAge(), other.getAge());
        }
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = getName.compareTo(other.getName());
        }
        return compare;
    }
}
```

This code snippet can also be used in a lambda expression:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int compare = Integer.compare(o1.getGroup(), o2.getGroup());
    if (compare == 0) {
        compare = Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge());
    }
    if (compare == 0) {
        compare = o1.getName.compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
    return compare;
});
```

Comment: Use `Integer.compare()` instead of subtraction, to prevent bad results on very large values.

Comment: Your first example doesn’t work. The compiler has no chance to deduce that `p` is a `Person`…