# How to sort int[] with multi-line lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326657/sorting-multiple-attribute-with-lambda-expressions) has an answer for how to sort a List with a multi-line lambda expression:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int cmp = o1.getGroup().compareTo(o2.getGroup());
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge());
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    return cmp;

});
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for a raw array `int[] arr`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (int1, int2) -> {
    // some lambda, various if-else statements for example
});
```

How to use a multi-line lambda expression in Arrays.sort() to sort a raw array?

I'm fine with any other approach (does not have to use `Arrays.`) as long as it uses lambda expressions (no comparators).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java comparator for arrays sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884385/java-comparator-for-arrays-sort)

Comment: Not very efficient, but `arr = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sorted((int1, int2) -> { /* your logic */ }).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();` would work.

Comment: @user85421 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're intent on doing it using only `lambdas` then this will work with both `lists` and `arrays`.  This presume your `group` and `age` fields are ints.

```
        Comparator<Item> comp = (o1, o2) -> {
            int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.getGroup(), o2.getGroup());
            cmp = cmp == 0 ? Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge()) : cmp;
            cmp = cmp == 0 ? o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) : cmp;
            return cmp;
        };

        list.sort(comp);

        Arrays.sort(items, comp);
```

But I would use a `List` and do it as follows:

```
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getGroup)
                .thenComparing(Item::getAge)
                .thenComparing(Item::getName));
```

And even your `lambda` expression is a `comparator`.  You can't compare without some sort of `Comparator` no matter how you construct it.