# Sorting Array of Custom Object in Java

Tags: java, comparison

I am trying to sort the Project end times from smallest to largest values.

I have created a list of custom objects called Project and am attempting to sort them based on a value returned by an accessor. I have overloaded the compare function and am receiving the error:

> The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Project[], new Comparator(){})

The code from my main is shown below, any and all help appreciated.

```
Collections.sort(projectList, new Comparator< Project>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Project project1, Project project2)
    {   
       return compareProjects(project1, project2);}
    }
);

public static int compareProjects(Project project1, Project project2)
{ 
    if (project1.getEndTime() > project2.getEndTime())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and my Project Class:

```
public Project(int projectNum, int start, int end)
{
    this.projectNum = projectNum;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.length = end - start;
}

public static int getEndTime()
{
    return end;
}
```

Comment: You could just use `return project1.getEndTime() - project2.getEndTime()` ... but what's the question?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator) might be helpful

Comment: `is not applicable for the arguments (Project[], new Comparator(){})`  I'm pretty sure that your answer right there.  `Project[]` is an array, not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Collections.sort operates on a List, and Arrays.sort operates on an array**

Need to changes `Project.class` , implement `Comparable interface`

```
class Project implements Comparable<Project> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Project o) {
        if (this.getEndTime() > o.getEndTime())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then in your `main.class`

```
Arrays.sort(projectList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never return `-1` (e.g `<`). However, I would suggest you use [`Integer.compareTo(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) which returns *the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y* like

```
public static int compareProjects(Project project1, Project project2) {
    return Integer.compare(project1.getEndTime(), project2.getEndTime());
}
```

Also, since `projectList` is an array of `Project` you can get it as a `List<Project>` with [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) like

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(projectList),
```