# sort array positive negative distance value

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have an array of distances calculated using (distance to) method
which contain both negative and positive values  looks like this

```
float num[] = {-123.81944, 34.56723, -133.40782};
```

when trying to use

```
Arrays.sort(num);
```

the result is

```
-123.81944     
-133.40782    
34.56723
```

which is incorrect since    -133.40782       location is closer than -123.81944

how can i sort the array to result like this

```
-133.40782      
-123.81944     
  34.56723
```

Comment: If you wish to sort the distances from a reference point , I feel your expected result is not correct. If we consider a line, a reference point and then on its left the negative distance and on its riggt the positive distance then sorting should be based on absolute value.

Comment: so your code as posted does not compile.  when simple changes are made so that it compiles the result is as you want - so what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `float` as data type, then you should declare the array as follows. Otherwise, you can use `double` as data type to avoid adding a suffix `f` to the numbers.

```
float[] num = {-123.81944f, 34.56723f, -133.40782f};
// or, double[] num = {-123.81944, 34.56723, -133.40782};
Arrays.sort(num);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```

**Output**

```
[-133.40782, -123.81944, 34.56723]
```

See a live [**demo**](https://ideone.com/Wg3lyV).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is an array`A` containing negative numbers, zero and  positive numbers. You need to sort them, how would you do it. Ofcourse you would consider the *natural ordering* and would sort as negative numbers followed by zero followed by positive numbers. This is what `Arrays.sort()` does.

If you wish to sort the distances from a reference point , I feel your expected result is not correct. If we consider a line, a reference point and then on its left the negative distance and on its riggt the positive distance then sorting should be based on absolute value.

Your business requirement is to do a custom sorting. For any sorting to work you need to have a logic for comparision.  For this java provides `Comparator`. You need to implement your business logic based comparision for sorting. [HINT : while comparing you can just compare the absolute value, Math.abs may help]

Floats end with `f` so apending `f` with each of your array elements is better.

For reference you can see another related question

[How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699141/504133)

Answer (score -1):

For me, with a standard Java JRE it works like (you) expected, but I had to turn the numbers in float literals. Otherwise it did not compile:

```
float num[] = new float[] {-123.81944f, 34.56723f, -133.40782f};
Arrays.sort(num);
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(" " + num[i]);
}
```

prints `-133.40782 -123.81944 34.56723`