# Sort primitive array with custom Comparator on Clojure

Tags: clojure

I would like to sort a primitive Java Array using a custom Comparator, but I am getting a type error.  I think the `comparator` function is creating a `Comparator<java.lang.Object>` rather than a `Comparator<Long>`, but I can't figure out how to get around this.

Here is a minimal example:

```
x.core=> (def x (double-array [4 3 5 6 7]))
#'x.core/x
x.core=> (java.util.Arrays/sort x (comparator #(> %1 %2)))

ClassCastException [D cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;  x.core/eval1524 (form-init5588058267991397340.clj:1)
```

I have tried adding different type hints to the comparator function, but frankly I am relatively new to the language and was basically just throwing darts.

I have deliberately simplified the example above to focus on the key question, which is a type error.  In the sections below I try to give some more detail to motivate the question and demonstrate why I am using a custom Comparator.

**Motivation**

What I am trying to do is duplicate R's `order` function, which works like this:

```
> x = c(7, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6)
> order(x)
[1] 5 2 4 6 3 7 1
> x[order(x)]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

As you can see it returns the permutation of indices that will sort its input vector.

Here is a working solution in Clojure:

```
(defn order
  "Permutation of indices sorted by x"
  [x]
  (let [v (vec x)]
    (sort-by #(v %) (range (count v)))))

x.core=> (order [7 2 5 3 1 4 6])
(4 1 3 5 2 6 0)
```

(Note that R is 1-indexed while Clojure is 0-indexed.)  The trick is to sort one vector (namely the indices of x `[0, 1, ..., (count x)]` by the vector x itself.

**R vs. Clojure Performance**

Unfortunately, I am bothered by the performance of this solution.  The R solution is *much* faster:

```
> x = runif(1000000)
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed
  0.041   0.004   0.046
```

Corresponding Clojure code:

```
x.core=> (def x (repeatedly 1000000 rand))
#'x.core/x
x.core=> (time (def y (order x)))
"Elapsed time: 2857.216452 msecs"
#'x.core/y
```

**Primitive Arrays the Solution?**

I discovered that primitive arrays tend to sort in comparable time to R:

```
> x = runif(1000000)
> system.time({ y = sort(x) })
   user  system elapsed
  0.061   0.005   0.069
```

vs.

```
x.core=> (def x (double-array (repeatedly 1000000 rand)))
#'x.core/x
x.core=> (time (java.util.Arrays/sort x))
"Elapsed time: 86.827277 msecs"
nil
```

This is the motivation for my attempt to use a custom Comparator with the java.util.Arrays class.  My hope is that the speed will be comparable to R.

I should add that I *can* use a custom Comparator with an ArrayList as shown below, but the performance was no better than my starting function:

```
(defn order2
  [x]
  (let [v (vec x)
        compx (comparator (fn [i j] (< (v i) (v j))))
        ix (java.util.ArrayList. (range (count v)))]
    (java.util.Collections/sort ix compx)
    (vec ix)))
```

Any help will be appreciated, even if you just want to give some general Clojure advice.  I'm still learning the language and having a lot of fun doing it.  :-)

---

*Edit*

Per Carcigenicate's answer below,

```
(defn order
  [x]
  (let [ix (int-array (range (count x)))]
    (vec (-> (java.util.Arrays/stream ix)
             (.boxed)
             (.sorted (fn [i j] (< (aget x i) (aget x j))))
             (.mapToInt
               (proxy [java.util.function.ToIntFunction] []
                 (applyAsInt [^long d] d)))
             (.toArray)))))
```

will work:

```
x.core=> (def x (double-array [5 3 1 3.14 -10]))
#'x.core/x
x.core=> (order x)
[4 2 1 3 0]
x.core=> (map #(aget x %) (order x))
(-10.0 1.0 3.0 3.14 5.0)
```

Unfortunately it's super slow.  I guess primitives might not be the answer after all.

Comment: I think the  problem is that the `java.util.Arrays/sort` doesn't seem to have an overload for double arrays that accepts a comparator. The only one that does is the `Object` array, which it's assuming you meant.

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator

Comment: If you are sorting primitives, why use a custom Comparator?  The only options are to sort in ascending or descending order, right?  Why not just use native sorting and then reverse the result, if desired?

Comment: This is just a simple example.  I actually wanted to sort one array by another, and I was just hoping that java.util.Arrays sort method on primitives would be faster than the naive solution.

Comment: @broken.eggshell Note that at the bottom of your edit you wrote "I guess primitives might not be the answer". Any solution using `java.util.Arrays/sort` will require boxing as far as I can tell. The problem isn't the speed of primitive arrays, but limitations of what you can actually do with them without requiring boxing. You may need to look into a third party library if you want to work on primitive arrays only. Unfortunately, I can't suggest such a library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but I don't think it's really a Clojure question after thinking about it, and I think the duplicate I proposed contains the answer. Like I said in my answer, this appears to be a oversight in planning on Java's part, so the best answer will be a workaround, or a third party library recommendation.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  It's really ultimately more of a Java question.  I guess I tied it to Clojure more in the hope that if I was doing something very un-Clojure, people would point it out.  I don't really know Java, but it definitely seems like a big missing piece in their library.  I did not realize that the T in Comparator<T> was required to be an object.  (In C++ templates I think they can be primitives.)

Comment: The guts of the R version of the order function are written in C (here for reference: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/596fdf2f9679ed3a7744b5d61168759b8944b1c7/src/main/radixsort.c#L1545-L1920). I find this pretty unreadable, but I guess it'd have to be translated to Java to have any hope of getting the same kind of performance in Clojure.

Comment: @broken.eggshell In terms of what you posted here, there isn't anything glaringly bad. It's well formatted and pretty standard looking. `#(v %)` is unnecessary though. You might as well just write `v`. If you want people to review some more substantial code that you've written, try posting it on Code Review. Always a good way of learning better ways to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Clojure implementation of the `order` function using quicksort with randomized pivots. It gets reasonably close to R: using your benchmark with a million doubles, I'm getting timings mostly in the 520-530 ms range, while R generally hovers around 500 ms here.

*Update:* With a very basic two-threaded version (2x quicksort followed by a merge step that produces the output vector) I'm getting noticeably improved timings – the worst benchmark average was 415 ms, otherwise I tend to get results in the 325-365 ms range. See end of this message for the two-threaded version, or if you prefer either version in gist form, here they are – [two-threaded](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/fa95ee12429ce45662a89ddeefaee526),
[single-threaded](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/11bbfd0b19b6357f533b192bf9da84ac).

Note that it pours its input into an array of doubles as an intermediate step and ultimately returns a vector of longs. Pouring a million doubles into a vector seems to take just over 30 ms on my box, so you could leave off that step if you're happy with an array result.

The main complication is the `invokePrim` – as of Clojure 1.9.0-RC1, a regular function call in that position would result in boxing. Other approaches are possible, but this works and seems straightforward enough.

See end of this message for some benchmark results.; the lower quantile result from the first run is actually the best reported result

```
(defn order2 [xs]
  (let [rnd (java.util.Random.)
        a1 (double-array xs)
        a2 (long-array (alength a1))]
    (dotimes [i (alength a2)]
      (aset a2 i i))
    (letfn [(quicksort [^long l ^long h]
              (if (< l h)
                (let [p (.invokePrim ^clojure.lang.IFn$LLL partition l h)]
                  (quicksort l (dec p))
                  (quicksort (inc p) h))))
            (partition ^long [^long l ^long h]
              (let [pidx (+ l (.nextInt rnd (- h l)))
                    pivot (aget a1 pidx)]
                (swap1 a1 pidx h)
                (swap2 a2 pidx h)
                (loop [i (dec l)
                       j l]
                  (if (< j h)
                    (if (< (aget a1 j) pivot)
                      (let [i (inc i)]
                        (swap1 a1 i j)
                        (swap2 a2 i j)
                        (recur i (inc j)))
                      (recur i (inc j)))
                    (let [i (inc i)]
                      (when (< (aget a1 h) (aget a1 i))
                        (swap1 a1 i h)
                        (swap2 a2 i h))
                      i)))))
            (swap1 [^doubles a ^long i ^long j]
              (let [tmp (aget a i)]
                (aset a i (aget a j))
                (aset a j tmp)))
            (swap2 [^longs a ^long i ^long j]
              (let [tmp (aget a i)]
                (aset a i (aget a j))
                (aset a j tmp)))]
      (quicksort 0 (dec (alength a1)))
      (vec a2))))
```

Benchmark results (NB. the first run uses `x` defined as in the question text – `(def x (repeatedly 1000000 rand))`; it also uses `c/bench`, whereas the following runs use `c/quick-bench`):

```
user> (c/bench (order2 x))
Evaluation count : 120 in 60 samples of 2 calls.
             Execution time mean : 522.485408 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 33.490530 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 470.089782 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 575.687990 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order2 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 527.020004 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 14.846061 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 507.175127 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 543.675752 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order2 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 513.476501 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 12.828449 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 497.164534 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 525.094463 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order2 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 529.826816 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 21.454522 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 508.547461 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 552.592925 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
```

Some R timings from the same box for comparison:

```
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.512   0.004   0.514 
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.496   0.000   0.496 
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.508   0.000   0.510 
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.508   0.000   0.513 
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.496   0.000   0.499 
> system.time({ y = order(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.500   0.000   0.502
```

*Update:* The two-threaded Clojure version:

```
(defn order3 [xs]
  (let [rnd (java.util.Random.)
        a1 (double-array xs)
        a2 (long-array (alength a1))]
    (dotimes [i (alength a2)]
      (aset a2 i i))
    (letfn [(quicksort [^long l ^long h]
              (if (< l h)
                (let [p (.invokePrim ^clojure.lang.IFn$LLL partition l h)]
                  (quicksort l (dec p))
                  (quicksort (inc p) h))))
            (partition ^long [^long l ^long h]
              (let [pidx (+ l (.nextInt rnd (- h l)))
                    pivot (aget a1 pidx)]
                (swap1 a1 pidx h)
                (swap2 a2 pidx h)
                (loop [i (dec l)
                       j l]
                  (if (< j h)
                    (if (< (aget a1 j) pivot)
                      (let [i (inc i)]
                        (swap1 a1 i j)
                        (swap2 a2 i j)
                        (recur i (inc j)))
                      (recur i (inc j)))
                    (let [i (inc i)]
                      (when (< (aget a1 h) (aget a1 i))
                        (swap1 a1 i h)
                        (swap2 a2 i h))
                      i)))))
            (swap1 [^doubles a ^long i ^long j]
              (let [tmp (aget a i)]
                (aset a i (aget a j))
                (aset a j tmp)))
            (swap2 [^longs a ^long i ^long j]
              (let [tmp (aget a i)]
                (aset a i (aget a j))
                (aset a j tmp)))]
      (let [lim (alength a1)
            mid (quot lim 2)
            f1 (future (quicksort 0 (dec mid)))
            f2 (future (quicksort mid (dec lim)))]
        @f1
        @f2
        (loop [out (transient [])
               i 0
               j mid]
          (cond
            (== i mid)
            (persistent!
              (if (== j lim)
                out
                (reduce (fn [out j]
                          (conj! out (aget a2 j)))
                  out
                  (range j lim))))

            (== j lim)
            (persistent!
              (reduce (fn [out i]
                        (conj! out (aget a2 i)))
                out
                (range i mid)))

            :else
            (let [ie (aget a1 i)
                  je (aget a1 j)]
              (if (< ie je)
                (recur (conj! out (aget a2 i)) (inc i) j)
                (recur (conj! out (aget a2 j)) i (inc j))))))))))
```

Some benchmark results for this one:

```
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order3 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 325.351056 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 3.511578 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 321.947510 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 330.375038 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order3 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 339.422989 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 19.929177 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 318.996436 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 366.113347 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order3 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 415.171336 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 13.624262 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 393.242455 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 428.881001 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns

Found 1 outliers in 6 samples (16.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (16.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 13.8889 % Variance is moderately inflated by outliers
nil
user> (let [x (repeatedly 1000000 rand)]
        (c/quick-bench (order3 x)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 324.547827 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 5.196817 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 318.541727 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 331.878289 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns
nil
user> (c/bench (order3 x))
Evaluation count : 180 in 60 samples of 3 calls.
             Execution time mean : 361.529793 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 45.285047 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 307.535934 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 446.679687 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.378363 ns

Found 1 outliers in 60 samples (1.6667 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 78.9377 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
nil
```

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful.  Sorry for my very slow response.  Clearly you are a Clojure master ;-)