# Java : Arrays.parallelSort on int[] using none standard comparator

Tags: java

For the current implementation I'm using an array of integers, Integer[], to use an external comparator. The order is not the 'natural' one but one defined externally.

```
Arrays.parallelSort(Integer[] array, Comparator<T> cmp);
```

Is there a way  using parallelSort with an array of integers, int[], and a user defined comparator ?

instead , something like :

```
Arrays.parallelSort(int[] array, IntComparator cmp);
```

Performance is the issue (think if you've 10mio ints)

Comment: java doesn't support custom comparator on primitive array.

Comment: That's why I'm asking... T can NOT be a primitive type

Comment: One approach, convert ```int[]``` to ```Integer[]```.```Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sort(cmparator).maptoInt(x -> x).toArray()```

Comment: Are you using Integer[] or int[]?

Comment: I'm using Integer[] but would like to use parallelSort with int[]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom comparator with the standard Java SE `Arrays.parallelSort(...)` methods on an array of integers, then it has to be an `Integer[]` rather than an `int[]`.

Here is an example (untested / based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045466/139985)

```
int[] ia = {99, 11, 7, 21, 4, 2};
ia = Arrays.stream(ia).
    boxed().
    parallel().
    sorted((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a)). // sort descending
    mapToInt(i -> i).
    toArray();
```

that converts from `int[]` to `Integer` and back using streams.

There are various other alternatives using 3rd party libraries:

- [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

Unfortunately, none of the answers to the above use a parallel sort, but there may be alternatives that do.

Comment: That's somehow what we're doing :-)

Comment: Well ... there ain't any alternative unless you want to look for an obscure 3rd-party library that does parallel sorting of `int[]` with a custom "comparator".