# Is it possible to sort an int[] array base on element string order with `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to sort an int array base on element's String value's reverser order.

I can do it like:

```
int[] nums = new int[]{9, 12, 67};
var list = Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(String::valueOf).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).toList();
```

Thinking of simple `Arrays.sort(nums)`'s performance far better than streaming api for large int[], I tried:

```
Arrays.sort(nums, (i, j) -> String.valueOf(j).compareTo(String.valueOf(i)));
```

it's an error:

> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that int[] conforms to T[]

Can I resolve this error ?

[image]

Comment: No. In a generic method the type argument (what `T` translates to) must be a reference type, it cannot be a primitive such as `int`. There have been talks about introducing type parameters that can also be primitive, but I don’t know whether anything will come out of it or when.

Comment: Related and maybe helpful: [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: A possible workaround would be if you can declare your array `Integer[]` rather than `int[]`.

Comment: One reason why this is impossible or at least unsuitable: the `Comparator<T>` interface is generic and takes a type argument representing the type of items to be compared, and in Java that needs to a reference type. There is no such thing as a comparator comparing `int` values. You would at the least need to use a `Comparator<Integer>` and box each `int` for each comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot use primitive types！like int、float、long....!

in `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`, `T[] <=> int[]`,`int[]` is not primitive type, but if you use `int[]` ,  in `Comparator<? super T>`, that `T` will be inferred to be of type `int`.

You can try to declare a variable of type `Comparator<? super int>` to see the effect.

```
Comparator<? super int> aaa;
```

This is not allowed.

Comment: @user16320675 My English is not very good, I don't know if I can express clearly.what  I mean is, if int[] is allowed, then it must be accepted that T will be deduced to be of type int, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.sort` expects an array of objects, not an array of primitive types like int[]. Maybe use an `Integer[]` array instead of an int[] array to sort based on the string value.

```
Integer[] nums = new Integer[]{9, 12, 67};
Arrays.sort(nums, (i, j) -> String.valueOf(j).compareTo(String.valueOf(i)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums)); // prints [67, 12, 9]
```

you can also use a `List<Integer>` and `Collections.sort` to sort the list:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(9, 12, 67);
Collections.sort(nums, Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i)), Comparator.reverseOrder()));
System.out.println(nums); // prints [67, 12, 9]
```